# Scikit-learn: precision_recall_fscore_support returns strange results

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, text-classification

I am doing some text minining/classification and attempt to evaluate performance with the `precision_recall_fscore_support` function from the `sklearn.metrics` module. I am not sure how I can create a really small example reproducing the problem, but maybe somebody can help even so because it is something obvious I am missing.

The aforementioned function returns among other things the support for each class. The documentation states

> **support: int (if average is not None) or array of int, shape = [n_unique_labels]** :
>   The number of occurrences of each label in y_true.

But in my case, the number of classes for which support is returned is not the same as the number of different classes in the testing data.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.5)

classifier = svm.SVC(kernel="linear")
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
prec, rec, fbeta, supp = precision_recall_fscore_support(y_test, y_pred)

print(len(classifier.classes_)) # prints 18
print(len(supp))                # prints 19
print(len(np.unique(y_test)))   # prints 18
```

How can this be? How can there be support for a class which is not in the data?

Comment: please correct your code (kernel=kernel="linear" is not valid) and provide sample data for which it happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what the problem is, but in my case there seems to be a mismatch between the classes learned by the classifier and the ones occurring in the test data. One can force the the function to compute the performance measures for the right classes by explicitly naming them.

```
prec, rec, fbeta, supp = precision_recall_fscore_support(y_test, y_pred, labels=classifier.classes_)
```